# Remote login using wget

Tags: php, linux, authentication, wget

I am trying to connect my site remotely. So I put

```
wget "http://mysite.org/index.php?page=login" --post-data "e-mail=mymail&password=mypassword"
```

but I keep on having this message (translated from french):

```
--2013-04-15 15:25:49--  http://mysite.org/index.php?page=login
Resolution of mysite.org (mysite.org )... 178.33.232.186
Connection to mysite.org  (mysite.org )|178.33.232.186|:80...connected.
requête HTTP transmise, waiting for response...200 OK
Longueur: non spécifié [text/html]
Saved in : «index.php?page=login.1»

    [ <=>                                                                                                                                                               ] 13.310      --.-K/s   ds 0,02s   

2013-04-15 15:25:50 (762 KB/s) - «index.php?page=login.1» saved [13310]
```

I get the same response when I put some random post data. It doesn't seem to login. Could someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

wget will not redirect you after a successful post, you will need to set a cookie. The documentation has an example: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Comment: Yes that's what I tried running : wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies/cookies.txt "http://mysite.org/index.php?page=login" --post-data "e-mail=mymail&password=mypassword", then running the wget command with the --load-cookies attribute. But I still have the same message. Btw, here's what I get in my coockies/cookies.txt file I have my site.org   FALSE   /       FALSE   0       PHPSESSID       9pjja9ga1pkatut7j3u3vc5l41